# Let $X$ be a set and ${\rm Sym}(X)$, the symmetric group on $X$. If $x,y\in X$, is there guaranteed to be an $f\in{\rm Sym}(X)$ such that $f(x)=y$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

> Let $X$ be a set and $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ be the symmetric group on $X$. If $x, y \in X$, is there guaranteed to be an $f \in \operatorname{Sym}(X)$ such that $f(x) = y$?

I think the answer is yes, but I'm having difficulty justifying it logically.

Comment: For example, take $f(x)=y$, $f(y)=x$, and $f(z)=z$ for $z\not\in\{x,y\}$; in this case, $f$ is its own inverse

Comment: @J.W.Tanner So we just have to prove that this is in fact in $Sym(X)$, which should be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply take the involution (transposition) $\;(x\,y)\;$, meaning: the bijective map

$$f:X\to X\;,\;\;f(a):=\begin{cases}y,&a=x\\{}\\x,&a=y\\{}\\a,&a\neq x,y\;\end{cases}\;,\;\;\;\;x\neq y$$

If $\;x=y\;$ then the identity map fulfills what you want.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure why I was making this so hard. I just have to build one permutation that fits the criteria.

Comment: @Code-Guru Exactly so

Comment: @DonAntonio:  when you typed convolution, did you mean *in*volution?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Of course. Too much harmonic analysis and stuff lately...Thanks, editing.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying set of ${\rm Sym}(X)$ is the set of all bijections from $X$ to $X$. Thus, for a given pair $(x,y)\in X\times X$, select a bijection $f$ such that $y=f(x)$; such an $f$ exists because we can construct it: designate some element $\star\in X$ then send $y$ to $\star$, $x$ to $y$, $\star$ to $x$, and the rest of $X$ to themselves. In other words,

$$f(\xi)=\begin{cases} y &: \xi=x,\\
x &: \xi=\star,\\
\star &: \xi=y,\\
\xi &: \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

But be careful with $\star=x$! In that case, take $f$ to be the involution $(xy)$, as I could have done from the get-go; and if $x=y$, the identity map will do.

Comment: I've decided to keep $\star$ in. I think it illustrates my thought process behind the construction of $f$.

Comment: Of course, if we choose $\star = x$, we will have to remove the rule, $x: \xi=\star$ otherwise $x$ maps both to itself and to $y$.

Comment: Thank you, @Code-Guru; well spotted!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the general idea here and see how your solution is similar to Don Antonio's. Both construct an $f$ by defining how it maps elements of $X$. I am accepting the other answer because it is a more direct construction.